# How can I make a checkbox bigger?

Tags: jquery, html, css

My web page uses checkboxes. They appear very small. I tried to make them bigger by using "font-size: 1.5em".  This didn't seem to change them at all.

Is there a simple way that I can make a checkbox bigger?

Thanks,

Answer (score 10):

You can do this using images.

CSS

```
#mycheckbox
{ 
    display: none; 
}

#mycheckbox + label
{ 
    float: left; 
    width: 200px; 
    height: 200px; 
    background: url('/path/to/photo_of_big_unchecked_box.png'); 
}

#mycheckbox:checked + label
{ 
    background: url('/path/to/photo_of_big_checked_box.png'); 
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" id="mycheckbox"><label for="mycheckbox"></label>
```

That's one way you might accomplish the goal.

**EDIT**

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/C2dxM/) is the working link for IE

Comment: Won't work. You've set `display: none` on it, so it will never be displayed.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it seems a little too obvious, but it works:

```
input[type='checkbox'] {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;        
}
```

It works as you might expect on IE and Chrome, and even though it doesn't look like it's bigger on Firefox you still get a larger hit box:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can not change the appearance of check boxes in most browsers.
Check this: http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/styling-form-controls-revisited/checkbox/

Try to add an element and make it change the status of the checkbox.
Check this for an example: http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

Comment: The question is not for raw HTML but for jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, CSS is kinda undefined with `<input>` making possibilities of modifying them limited. Various browsers do things differently. `width` and `height` practically work on checkboxes only in Internet Explorer.

Various solutions appeared, for example [emulating checkboxes using JS, so those can be styled](http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/).

Answer (score 1):

AS you cant change the appearance of checkboxes cross browser compatible, I suggest, to use something like [Ryan Fait describes in his blog](http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/). This technique allows you to use custom graphics for your checkboxes.

---

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS zoom tag.

```css
h6 {
  zoom: 5;
}
```

```html
<h6><input type="checkbox"></h6>
```